# How to use Tivix django-cron app

Tags: django, cron, django-cron

I got exact same problem described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091776/creating-a-regular-email), but the answer doesn't help at all. In short, I am using [Tivix django-cron](https://github.com/Tivix/django-cron/issues/21), the cron job is not running at regular basis.

To illustrate the problem, the following cron job class is intended to send email every min once running `runcrons` command. But in fact, it only sends out one email and no more. That defeats the purpose of cron... What am I missing?

```
class TestCron(CronJobBase):
    schedule = Schedule(run_every_mins=1)
    code = 'test_cron_philip'

    def do(self):
        send_mail('cron test', 'body is test body', 'coach_zhong@163.com',
                  ['admin@dessert.webfactional.com'],fail_silently=False)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you miss something ("runcrons" is not background deamon). From documentation:

> "Now everytime you run the management command python manage.py
>   runcrons all the crons will run **if required**. Depending on the
>   application the management command can be called from the Unix crontab
>   as often as required. Every 5 minutes usually works for most of my
>   applications."

That means you have to put "runcrons" command in your crontab.

**Example:**

You have some CronJob that do something every 30 min.

To get this running you must edit you **crontab** (linux, mac) or **task scheduler** (windows) to run "python manage.py runcrons" for every, let say 1 min.

If you get this running, your CronJob will be pinged every 1 min and run if necessary (every 30 min or whatever value you have set).

Hope this helps.

Comment: i had this in my crontab file:* * * * * root python /home/nash/djangocode/zingyhomes_new/manage.py runcrons but it still does not works out ? please help .